# Word for someone who feels that they deserve all the bad things that have happened to them

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

Question is in the title, basically. Recently I was talking to a friend who feels like they deserve anything bad that happens to them. I thought this would fall under self-pity, but the person isn't blaming others or blaming factors outside of their control that have put them in their current predicament.

Comment: It's not quite what you're looking for, but your description closely parallels a "defeatist".

Comment: Related but not quite right: remorseful. Why not? Because your friend may, for all we know, consider it worth it. Remorse implies regret, I think.

Comment: Is it a God thing?

Comment: An ***Ancient Mariner***, of course.

Comment: I quite like "defeatist". I think there is definitely some of that in my friend.

Comment: Are they correct?  Is "if the shoe fits, wear it." a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like **"Derisory" (adj.)**

> expressing a belief that something or someone is ridiculous or without value : expressing derision
>
> -Merriam Webster

So you could say that your friend is self-derisory for not believing they are worthy of good experiences or feelings.

Similarly, and perhaps more commonly: **"Deprecating" (v.)**

> to criticize or express disapproval of (someone or something)
>
> -Merriam Webster

A little less harsh than derision, self-deprecation can often take a humorous slant to self-criticism.

Comment: I think self-derisory might just be it. I think his unfounded pessimism regarding life does stem from not valuing himself enough.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of phrases/idioms to echo the word you're trying to come up with such as

> what goes around comes around

or

> actions have consequences

If your friend acknowledges these phrases and the existence of karma, which is the belief that rewards follow good deeds while punishments follow bad deeds, then I would describe him or her as feeling "*blameworthy*". From Merriam-Webster,

> being at fault :  deserving blame

I chose this word because it seems like your friend feels responsible for a bad deed and deserving of any punishment. Good synonyms include "*guilty*", "*reprehensible*", and "*culpable*". All of these can express your friend's feelings.

Comment: All good terms, I think. But suppose that the person hasn't necessarily done something bad, but still feels this way? Though I suppose they could be feeling guilt for a deed long since committed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a saying, that misery loves company.
It's being comfortable being miserable,
It is a self-loathing that is a familiar friend,
It is a way of life, that drives a person to accept the abnormal, such as the severity and the cruelties of life as a perverse normality, expected and deserved.
It is a redefining of oneself.
It is what causes the whip of a Taskmaster, to be felt has purpose, care, and personal attention in the mind of a Slave.
It is not what we are born with however it is instilled into us that this is Who We Are, usually through early childhood trauma either or both physical and emotional.
As a Christian counselor we use the term "Inferiority Disorder" with the diagnosis of "Social Anxiety complex."
It is I think, to prove yourself in a negative area because you are terrified in another area, real or imagined.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they have a **martyr complex** ?

From Wikipedia ...

> [Martyr complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyr_complex) — In psychology a person who has a martyr complex, sometimes associated with the term victim complex, desires the feeling of being a martyr for his/her own sake, seeking out suffering or persecution because it either feeds a psychological need, or a desire to avoid responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Self condemnation: The blaming of oneself